# How do I associate multiple socketId's to one nickname in an object for socket.io and express.js?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I'm working on this node chat-widget: https://github.com/wwwizzarrdry/mini_chat/

1. You can open multiple tabs/windows under the same nickname and chat works fine (I.e. All messages appear to come from the appropriate user regardless of which window they send from).
2. The problem is with my whisper function. When sending a private message to a user, I can only get it to send to the last socketId for that user. So if 4 windows are open, the whisper is only received in the last window.

Q: How do I allow multiple sockets to be opened under the same nickname, but then maintain the whisper functionality across all windows for that user?
I was able to establish a single sessionId for all connected users, but then had no idea how to reassign a socket to a user once they had been established.

App.js Key Blocks:

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    users = {};

    server.listen(3000);

    ........

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var query = Chat.find({});
    query.sort('-created').limit(25).exec(function(err, docs){
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit('load old msgs', docs);
    });

    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
            if (data in users){
                    callback(false);
            } else{
                    callback(true);
                    socket.nickname = data;
                    users[socket.nickname] = socket;
                    updateNicknames();
            }
    });

    function updateNicknames(){
            io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
    }

    .......

    socket.on('send message', function(data, callback){
    var msg = data.trim();
    console.log('after trimming message is: ' + msg);
    if(msg.substr(0,3) === '/w '){
        msg = msg.substr(3);
        var ind = msg.indexOf(' ');
        if(ind !== -1){
            var name = msg.substring(0, ind);
            var msg = msg.substring(ind + 1);
            if(name in users){
                users[name].emit('whisper', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
                console.log('message sent is: ' + msg);
                console.log('Whisper!');
            } else{
                callback('Error!  Enter a valid user.');
            }
        } else{
            callback('Error!  Please enter a message for your whisper.');
        }
    } else{
        var newMsg = new Chat({msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
        newMsg.save(function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
             io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
        });
    }

    .......
```

UPDATE: Using 'rooms' worked beautifully.

```
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
            if (data in users){
                    callback(true);
                    socket.nickname = data;
                    users[socket.nickname] = socket;
                    **socket.join(socket.nickname);**
                    updateNicknames();
            } else{
                    callback(true);
                    socket.nickname = data;
                    users[socket.nickname] = socket;
                    **rooms.push(socket.nickname);
                    socket.join(socket.nickname);**
                    updateNicknames();
            }
    });

    .......

    socket.on('send message', function(data, callback){
            var msg = data.trim();
            console.log('after trimming message is: ' + msg);
            if(msg.substr(0,3) === '/w '){
                    msg = msg.substr(3);
                    var ind = msg.indexOf(' ');
                    if(ind !== -1){
                            var name = msg.substring(0, ind);
                            var msg = msg.substring(ind + 1);
                            if(name in users){
                                      **io.sockets.in(name).emit('whisper', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});**
                                      *//users[name].emit('whisper', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});*
                                      console.log('message sent is: ' + msg);
                                      console.log('Whisper!');
                            } else{
                                    callback('Error!  Enter a valid user.');
                            }
                    } else{
                            callback('Error!  Please enter a message for your whisper.');
                    }
            } else{
                    var newMsg = new Chat({msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
                    newMsg.save(function(err){
                            if(err) throw err;
                            io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
                    });
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

- Create a room for each set of windows/tabs that run under the same nickname. From [socket.io's docs](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms):

> Rooms allow simple partitioning of the connected clients. This allows
>   events to be emitted to subsets of the connected client list, and
>   gives a simple method of managing them.

Basically, for each nickname, create a room (might be a unique hash of the nickname), and whenever you need to whisper something, simply send it to that room.

- Track the socket ids for all windows/tabs specific to each client, and save them in a db. Then, once you need to broadcast a whisper, simply query all the ids, and send them a `whisper` message. The cons of this method is that you need some housekeeping over your db (removing ids of disconnected sockets, primarily).

Personally, I would go with the first method, simply because it would make for a good learning experience.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That solution was simple, quick and works nicely.